# Possible to use MonkeyTalk with non-native language app?

Tags: iphone, testing, automation

I am trying to do some automated testing on a product that was written in my companies proprietary language. This language gives us the ability to write one set of code for both Android and iOS. I'm wondering if I can use `MonkeyTalk` to do automated testing on this app. I've been told that you have to run `MonkeyTalk` in the native language in order to use it.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

In What so ever language you write your application, you need to build the project using respective native compilers, Ex: On IOS, you need to compiler you project using Xcode, you can include the monkey talk agents in you build project while compiling the code in the respective platforms. All you need to do is to include the AGENT SDK while building the project, you don't need to make any code changes, os i think you can use MonkeyTalk for your project.

Hope this helps.